# LED strip with 12v power connected to ESP32

Tags: power, led, esp32

I'm looking at controlling a ws2811 strip and I have seen mention that you should share the same ground between the strip and the controller, which does make sense.
I do not currently have a proper power supply that will supply the full range of 12,5 and 3 volts but what I do have is one of these breadboard power supplies:

https://tinkersphere.com/906-thickbox_default/breadboard-power-supply-module-33v-5v-arduino-raspberry-pi-compatible.jpg

If using a correctly rated 12v power supply into this am I able to take a feed from the 12v line and hook the strip up to that and still have the rest function correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK the majority of ws2811 strips are powered at 5V; if you have a 12V one this may work, provided that you give the strip enough current (consider 60mA for each LED at 5V, or 60mA for three LEDs if you have the 12V version with 3 LEDs per strip segment)

Comment: Its definitely a 12v one (I have measured it to make sure it was not just mislabelled), which caught me off guard given what I had read, it may be because it is a slightly longer strip at 5m. I will work out the draw as you have suggested to make sure. Thank you very much for your answer, exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: I have also seen some (older?) strip where there was a WS2811 chip powered at 12V controlling three RGB leds (all the three leds will have the same color); maybe this is yours... like [this rigid pcb strip](https://is.alicdn.com/img/pb/997/230/474/474230997_458.jpg)

Comment: You are correct, that looks spot on. 3 LED's per chip. This is the strip I have, they were on a dirt cheap offer.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/DreamColor-MINGER-Waterproof-Flexible-Lighting/dp/B0799B8QN7/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1543933680&sr=8-3&keywords=dreamcolor

Comment: Looking at the picture, you can cut them three at a time, so I think they are the same as the pcb strip I linked (only those ones had wires, while yours is continuous). I think you will see that you will be able to individually address only three leds at a time, rather than each led independently. In any case, if you want to use an arduino you don't need that module; just attach the 12V to the strip, and then power the arduino through the VIN pin (NOT the 5V pin, use the barrel connector or the Vin pin) and, of course, the ground

Comment: @frarugi87 he isn't using an Arduino but an EPS32. Depending on which board, it may not have a VIN pin.

Comment: 12v->3.3v on an LDO driving an ESP32 will get quite hot, maybe hot enough to shut down the 1117-3.3.  Even on the TO-220 version, I need an inch or two of heatsink to keep them under burning hot to the human touch. I would get a cheap adjustable buck converter or a bigger package LDO

Comment: Thank you all for your input, ill take it all onboard. I powered the ESP32 from the 5v pin and I managed to get it working last night for a while before the power supply popped and started passing 9v down the 5v output. @dandavis Do these chips also tend to have problems when running 12v to 5v as well or is it just the 3.3v? Either way, I have ordered some new of these cheap supplies as well as a 12v to 5v buck converter. Thank you all for the guidance!

Comment: 12v to 5v will generate almost as much heat as 12v to 3.3v, so probably.